# How to test that a variable is type Map or Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, maps

In ES6, how can I test if a variable is an `Array` or a `Map`?

`instance.constructor.name === 'Map'` is a risky habit, even if it's core type, doing this with your own class when minified will break the test.

What is the most reliable way to verify that the variable is an instance of [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Map)

Comment: An array is *never* a `Map`, they're entirely different constructs.

Comment: I noticed that you edited your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. Doing so is bad form, because it confuses readers, and makes the people who wrote those answers look like idiots, because their answer no longer matches the question. Please consider rolling back your edit to the previous version.

Answer (score 6):

```js
const getType = obj => Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1);

const isArray = obj => getType(obj) === 'Array';

const isMap = obj => getType(obj) === 'Map';


const arr = [];

console.log(isArray(arr)); // true


const map = new Map();

console.log(isMap(map)); // true
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `instanceof`. It will return true/false if the object is a map or not

```js
var a = new Map;
console.log(a instanceof Map);
```

For checking array use isArray method

```js
var a= new Array;
console.log(Array.isArray(a))
```

Comment: `instanceof` will not work if you're jumping between contexts like a different `window`. I personally don't recommend it. Although, I tested it out in the latest Chrome; it works fine. This wasn't the case in 2015, so it's possible this varies per browser.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of checking the constructor's `.name` (string) property, just check whether the constructor itself is `=== Map`:

```js
const m = new Map();
console.log(m.constructor === Map);
```

Comment: If you're in a different `window` context, this won't work. You might ask how you get yourself in this situation, but you might have code running in the main window checking for a `Map` in the newly-opened window.

Answer (score 3):

You could check with [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), because [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is no [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/).

For checking the instance, you could take the [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

```js
var array = [],
    map = new Map;
    
console.log(Array.isArray(array)); //  true
console.log(Array.isArray(map));   // false
console.log(array instanceof Map); // false
console.log(map instanceof Map);   //  true
```

Comment: But then it can be one or the other, what about to really test if it's a map ?

Comment: if you only have an array or a map, you could take `Array.isArray`, otherwise you need to check the instance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to test if an [`Array`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array-objects) is a [`Map`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-map-objects) in JavaScript, since an `Array` is an `Array`, it can never be a `Map`.

In fact, they are not even the same kind of collection, an `Array` is an [*indexed collection*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-indexed-collections) whereas a `Map` is a [*keyed collection*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-keyed-collections).

Comment: Incorrect. This question is not invalid. I have a `clone()` method where anything can be passed to it. I want to know if it's a Map, a Set, or an Array (or a million other things). This is a valid question. I do need to test it.

Comment: The question was edited to ask something different *after* I wrote my answer. Obviously, I couldn't have known that the question would be changed into something different when I wrote my answer, when the question had not been changed yet at that time. My answer is valid for the question that was asked at the time that I was answering it. Changing the question in a way that invalidates existing answer is considered bad style on SO, I will ask the OP to roll back the edit. Unfortunately, answerers are not notified when the question is changed. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: For reference, at the time I answered the question, the question asked "In ES6, how can I test if an `Array` is a `Map`?" And I believe my answer is 100% correct: an `Array` is always an `Array` and never a `Map`, therefore it is not necessary to test whether an `Array` is a `Map`.

Comment: I will also note that the question as it is now makes no sense: the subject line asks how to test the type of a variable, but variables don't have types in ECMAScript. (They do in TypeScript, for example, but the question isn't about TypeScript.)

Comment: Oh. I didn't realize the question had changed. I see.

Comment: Your statement that variables don't have types in ECMAScript is not true. You don't declare types, but you have a `typeof` operator that tells you exactly that - what type it is. The number 5 and the string "5" are definitely not the same type.

Comment: The `typeof` operator tells you the type of a *value*, not of a *variable*. Variables don't have types in ECMAScript, only values do.

Answer (score 1):

An Array can naver be a Map in javascript. You may however be confused with Object or map. To check if the javascript variable is `Map` you can make use of [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

```
instance instanceof Map
```

To test is the variable is an instance of an Array, you can write [`Array.isArray(instance)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```js
var instance = new Map;
console.log(instance instanceof Map); // true
console.log(instance instanceof Array); //false
```

Comment: Incorrect. This question is not invalid. I have a `clone()` method where anything can be passed to it. I want to know if it's a Map, a Set, or an Array. This is a valid question, and your answer (including the `instanceof` part in other windows/contexts) is completely wrong.